# Pandas: trouble with to_excel using a grouped dataframe

Tags: excel, group-by, pandas

I am trying to save a dataframe I created using groupby into an excel file, with the to_excel function. When I preview the data in ipython notebook, it appears as desired. The groupby code is simple:

```
    grouped = teach_freq.groupby(['Focal','follow','Activity'])
    grouped.head()

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    MultiIndex: 1797 entries, (10107.0, 192.0, ff, 25220.0) to (53704.0, 142.0, ss.rn, 18823.0)
    Data columns (total 16 columns):
    Epoch         1790  non-null values
    follow        1797  non-null values
    T_Opp         1797  non-null values
    T_Dir         1797  non-null values
    T_Enh         1797  non-null values
    T_SocTol      1797  non-null values
```

... and so on
        dtypes: float64(3), int64(6), object(7)

The to_excel code is also simple:

```
    grouped.to_excel('filename.xls', sheet_name='sheet1')
```

When I run this last code, only a few lines of data make it to the excel file (about 3 out of nearly 1800 lines of data. I get a preview of a different portion of the data in ipython notebook that looks like this:

```
   Focal  follow  Activity     
   10107  192     ff               None
   10212  187     rn.ss            None
   194            hc               None
                  pa               None
   10213  166     hr.hg            None
                  pa               None
                  sr.hg            None
                  sr.hl            None
```

These data appear to be only the 3 columns I've grouped by, plus a column of None, which doesn't exist in my dataframe. In the file, I get 6 lines of correctly formatted data, headings and all. If I keep an eye on the file that's being written to in Finder, the size varies up and down as the to_excel line of code, which I think suggests that it is writing small chunks of data to the file at a time, but over-writing each one with the next.

The final file size is tiny (6KB) but at some points while the code is running, it is larger (up to 32KB).

Finally, the last few lines of data that are displayed in the ipython data appear to be the lines just before those that are successfully written to the excel file, which suggests that for some reason it's only saving those lines of data that are past the ipython notebook preview limit. I'm not sure why anyone would want that as a feature, or why it would function this way.

This is bizarre, I'm hoping someone can explain to me why this is happening. I've looked at the groupby and to_excel documentation and browsed for anyone with a similar problem, but haven't found it. I've used to_excel for dataframes with this same data, that are not grouped, and haven't had any similar problems. I actually am not even clear on why I'm getting output within the notebook, as the other times I have used to_excel, I only see output in the excel file itself.

Comment: You say "save a dataframe I created using groupby into an excel file", but I don't see that in your code.  `groupby` doesn't return a `DataFrame`, it returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, which I suspect is the issue.  To make sure, is there any code you left out?

Comment: Nope, I didn't leave out code - just making stupid beginner mistakes.

Comment: Almost by definition, beginners can't make stupid mistakes: they're beginners.  It takes experience to make stupid mistakes, the accumulation of which is expertise. ;^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see the full docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html)

The problem is you are trying to operate on a `DataFrameGroupby` object, which allows *some* actions on the underlying DataFrame. However you need to *do* something to the groupby object to create a new dataframe.

The `to_excel` shouldn't work (and in fact in upcoming 0.13 release will be disabled).

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   X  Y
0  B  1
1  B  2
2  A  3
3  A  4

In [3]: df.groupby('X')
Out[3]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x40523d0>

In [4]: df.groupby('X').sum()
Out[4]: 
   Y
X   
A  7
B  3

In [5]: type(df.groupby('X').sum())
Out[5]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So you need to apply an aggregation operation (e.g. `sum`, or use `apply`) to your grouped frame, which will then create a new frame, which you can `to_excel`.

Comment: This makes sense. I suppose I should be using code that just sorts if I want to organize by groups for the output, but not apply any aggregation operations. Thanks for the clear explanation - the fact that some output did make it to the excel file made me think it ought to work the way I supposed, but obviously not.

Comment: yep....if you truly do want to group (outside of excel), then you should aggregate as well, otherwise, sorting is a good compromise

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but I found that if I use the following code, the to_excel function works properly. But this seems inconsistent with the typical to_excel usage, so I'm still hoping someone can explain this to me.

```
    grouped.head().to_excel('PREVIEW.xls')
```

It also doesn't seem like this is a permanent solution, as head() won't display all the data on a larger file. I'm actually a bit confused about why it does so, here. But it works, so I'm going with it and hoping someone can refer me to the right documentation so that I can understand why this is the case.

Answer (score -1):

i had same problem and i used 
grouped.first().to_excel('filename.xls')
NB: head() doesnt write all values i think it wrote just first 5 rows or smthng like that

Comment: Please, improve the format of your answer. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer